# Dagger Android for custom class possible?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I am trying to make dagger-android work with Conductor (or any custom class). I tried replicating everything that AndroidSupportInjectionModule (and friends) do, which in my mind is the same kind of a custom class handling.

However I get

```
C:\Users\ursus\AndroidStudioProjects\...\ControllersModule.java:15: error: com.foo.bar.ChannelsController is not a framework type
    public abstract com.foo.bar.ChannelsController channelsController();
```

So, my "library" code

```
package com.foo.bar

import com.bluelinelabs.conductor.Controller;
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.android.AndroidInjectionModule;
import dagger.android.AndroidInjector;
import dagger.internal.Beta;
import dagger.multibindings.Multibinds;

import java.util.Map;

@Beta
@Module(includes = AndroidInjectionModule.class)
public abstract class ConductorInjectionModule {

    private ConductorInjectionModule() {
    }

    @Multibinds
    abstract Map<Class<? extends Controller>, AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Controller>> controllerInjectorFactories();

    @Multibinds
    abstract Map<String, AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Controller>> controllerInjectorFactoriesWithStringKeys();
}
```

I dont even get compiled, so presuming pasting ConductorInjection & HasControllerInjector is pointless

Usage:

```
@Module
abstract class AppModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity
    @ContributesAndroidInjector abstract fun channelsController(): ChannelsController
}

class App : Application(), HasActivityInjector, HasControllerInjector {

    @Inject lateinit var activityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>
    @Inject lateinit var controllerInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Controller>

    private lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .applicationContext(this)
            .build()
            .apply {
                inject(this@App)
            }
    }

    override fun activityInjector() = activityInjector
    override fun controllerInjector() = controllerInjector
}

@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        ConductorInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        NetModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(app: App)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun applicationContext(context: Context): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}


implementation deps.dagger.runtime
implementation deps.dagger.androidRuntime
kapt deps.dagger.compiler
kapt deps.dagger.androidCompiler
```

where it is all "2.19" version (have tried 2.16)

AGP "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-rc02" (have tried 3.2.1 stable)

Any clue? In my mind it all should work as its the same thing `dagger-android-support` does

Comment: I'm assuming you want to use this with `AndroidInjection::inject`?  That only supports framework types for injection.  Indeed `AndroidInjector<T>` states : <T> a concrete subtype of a core Android type so `? extends Controller` will not work. From this perspective the error you are getting makes sense.

Comment: No no, I am creating my own ConductorInjection::inject which gets the dispatchinginjector from App object (same stuff AndroidSupportInjection does for appcompat fragment). But anyways, what you are saying would crash at runtime, im not even compiling

Comment: Ah I see, I'm going to go out on a limb and say it's this annotation : `@ContributesAndroidInjector` on your non platform type.

Comment: Well, yes, but how come that annotation works for appcompat fragments? By this logic it shouldnt, or my case should as well. Isnt appcompat fragment nonplatform type as well?

Comment: Unless they hacked appcompat into there, but, I dont see it since dagger-android doesnt include appcompat
`
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.19
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.19
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.19 (*)
|    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0`

Comment: well it wouldn't make sense as dagger,android does not know or rely on dagger.android.support, and clearly `@ContributesAndroidInjector` is part of dagger.android - I'm looking through the source now .. I can't see any implementation differences between yours and `AndroidSupportInjectionModule`

Comment: @MarkKeen I by a chance upgraded to dagger 2.20 and it works now, facepalm

Comment: maybe you need to create your own annotation class `ConductorKey` like `FragmentKey` or `ActivityKey` - the generated code uses these as the key with `@Binds @IntoMap`? Just seen your updated comment .. wow .. got to love dagger .. as Jake Wharton would put it "it's so simple..."

Comment: maybe, im not at that yet, but @contributesinjector should work regardless, now in 2.20 does

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> error: com.foo.bar.ChannelsController is not a framework type

So the question to answer is, "how does dagger-android know what a framework type is or not".

The answer can be found in [this commit to Dagger-Android](https://github.com/google/dagger/commit/221f000e3d608637d5275b5c4650733c7668d450#diff-fc863e1e053e4df1ceffb2fe9bd43fa8#L49-L61) between 2.19 and 2.20, where they "removed the old way of doing things for better compatibility with AndroidX".

So as we can see in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53891780/2413303 ,

> ```
>    /**    
>     * Returns the Android framework types available to the compiler, keyed by their associated {@code 
>     * dagger.android} {@link MapKey}s. This will always contain the types that are defined by the 
>     * framework, and only contain the support library types if they are on the classpath of the   
>     * current compilation.    
>     */    
>    static ImmutableMap<Class<? extends Annotation>, TypeMirror> frameworkTypesByMapKey(   
>        Elements elements) {   
>      return ImmutableMap.copyOf(  
>          Stream.of(   
>                  elements.getPackageElement("dagger.android"),    
>                  elements.getPackageElement("dagger.android.support"))    
>              .filter(packageElement -> packageElement != null)    
>              .flatMap(packageElement -> typesIn(packageElement.getEnclosedElements()).stream())   
>              .filter(AndroidMapKeys::isNotAndroidInjectionKey)    
>              .filter(type -> isAnnotationPresent(type, MapKey.class)) 
>              .filter(mapKey -> mapKey.getAnnotation(MapKey.class).unwrapValue())  
>              .flatMap(AndroidMapKeys::classForAnnotationElement)  
>              .collect(toMap(key -> key, key -> mapKeyValue(key, elements)))); 
>    }
> ```

they had code that checked their own `@MapKey` types in `dagger.android` and `dagger.android.support` packages, that looked like this:

```
// java/dagger/android/support/FragmentKey.java

 @Beta  
 @MapKey    
 @Documented    
 @Target(METHOD)    
 @Deprecated    
 public @interface FragmentKey {    
   Class<? extends Fragment> value();   
 }
```

So they read the framework types based on what `@MapKey`s were available in the `dagger.android` and `dagger.android.support` packages.

---

Apparently they removed this check in 2.20 so now you can inject whatever you want. Rejoice!

But otherwise you could actually hack it in such a way that you'd add a `@ControllerKey` and a `@ViewKey` in `dagger.android` package in your project, and it'd actually likely work with 2.19.

The tests that were checking for errors in "is not a framework type" are also removed in that commit.

Ah, and

```
@Multibinds
abstract Map<String, AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Controller>> controllerInjectorFactoriesWithStringKeys();
```

You can remove this part too with 2.20, all you need now is `AndroidInjectionModule`.

Answer (score 2):

For future travelers, they were hardcoding some appcompat stuff in the annot. processor, thats why appcompat fragments worked.

[image]

update to dagger 2.20, it will magically work